# Hide the powershell consol when I use a form

Tags: forms, powershell, console, hide

I explain my situation so I create a form but when I execute the *.ps1 I have the form and the console open.
So I would know if it's possible to hide the console 
Thank's for your report :)

Comment: `PowerShell.exe -windowstyle hidden { your script.. }`

Comment: Thank's a lot for your answer

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh You can't use a scriptblock to pass commands to `powershell.exe` unless you're invoking it from within powershell already (in which case, the parser is just turning it into a string anyways)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a shortcut to your script and execute it like below:

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -file "C:\scripts\yourscript.ps1"
```

Comment: Thank's you very much